# Background Music Stops after Call Interruption in iOS 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8, avaudioplayer, background-music

thanks in advance.

I have to play music in background using `AVAudioPlayer` but my `background music` not working after `call interruption`. Please tell me any solution for that.

Thanks